# How to write this non-linear PDE with the finite volume method?

Tags: pde, finite-volume, advection-diffusion

I wish to solve a coupled system of non-linear equation of this form,

$$
u_t = -(\mathcal{F})_x + f(x,u,w) \\
w_t = \mathcal{F} + g(x,u,w)
$$

by stepping the equations forward in time.  The first equation is the *advection-diffusion equation* with non-linear reaction term, and where the *flux* has the definition,

$$\mathcal{F}=au-du_x$$

**First equation**

It is [straight forward to write this using the finite volume method](http://danieljfarrell.github.io/FVM/finite_volume_method.html),

$$
\int_{\Omega}u_t~dx = -\int_{\Omega}(\mathcal{F})_x~dx + \int_{\Omega}f(x,u,w)~dx \\
\tilde{u}_t = \frac{1}{h_j}\left( -\mathcal{F}_{j+\frac{1}{2}} +  \mathcal{F}_{j-\frac{1}{2}} \right) + \tilde{f}(x_j,u_j,w_j)
$$

where $h_j$ is the width (not volume because I am considering 1D only) of the $j$-th cell.

**Second equation**

However, how should the second equation be written, can I do the following?

$$
\int_{\Omega}w_t~dx = \int_{\Omega}\mathcal{F}~dx + \int_{\Omega}g(x,u,w)~dx \\
\tilde{w}_t = \frac{1}{h_j}\mathcal{F}_jh_j + \tilde{g}(x_j,u_j,w_j)
$$

Moreover, if we assume that the flux in the $j$-th cell is constant across the cell then the  integral becomes,

$$
\int_{\Omega}\mathcal{F}~dx = \mathcal{F}_jh_j
$$

This is simply base $\times$ height of the cell, but because I want to know the cell average values I divide again by the cell width. Finally I get the following for the second equation,

$$
\tilde{w}_t = \mathcal{F}_j + \tilde{g}(x_j,u_j,w_j)
$$

**Q1.** Is this correct?

In terms of implementation I know 3 of the terms in $\mathcal{F}_j$, they are:

- $a_j$, the cell advection velocity,
- $d_j$, the cell diffusion coefficient,
- $u_j$, the cell mass concentration,

However, $u_x$ is not known.

**Q2.** Can I simply write $u_x$ using the values of concentration interpolated to the cell faces? For example,

$$
u_x = \frac{1}{h_j}\left( u_{j+\frac{1}{2}} - u_{j-\frac{1}{2}} \right)
$$

This doesn't seem quite right because I was taught that in the finite-volume method, concentrations are defined in the cells and fluxes are defined on the faces.

**Update**

Regarding definition of fluxes.

For the **first equation** I define the fluxes as,

$$
\mathcal{F}_{j+\frac{1}{2}} = a_{j+\frac{1}{2}}\left( \frac{h_{j+1}}{2h_{+}} u_j + \frac{h_j}{2h_{+}} u_{j+1} \right) - d_{j+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{u_{j+1}-u_j}{h_{+}}
$$

$$
\mathcal{F}_{j-\frac{1}{2}} = a_{j-\frac{1}{2}}\left( \frac{h_{j}}{2h_{-}} u_{j-1} + \frac{h_{j-1}}{2h_{-}} u_{j} \right) - d_{j-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{u_{j}-u_{j-1}}{h_{-}}
$$

where $h_j$ is the cell width, and $h_{\pm}$ are the centroid distances in the forward and backward direction.

Here linear interpolation is used to define the variable at the cell faces $u(x_{j-1/2})$ and $u(x_{j+1/2})$, and forward difference and backward difference  is used to define $u_x(x_{j+1/2})$ and $u_x(x_{j-1/2})$. This gives a central discretisation for both the advection and diffusion terms (however, [upwinding can still be introduced easily](http://danieljfarrell.github.io/FVM/finite_volume_method.html)).

However for the **second equation** the flux is *not* defined on the cell's left and right face, **it is defined as the cell average**, so I need to use a different definition for,

$$
\mathcal{F}_j = a(x_j)u(x_j) - d(x_j)u_x(x_j)
$$

Clearly, $a(x_j)$, $u(x_j)$, and $d(x_j)$ are already known. The only term than needs defining for the second equation is $u_x(x_j)$. So maybe I could use,

$$
u_x(x_j) = \frac{1}{h_j}\left( u_{j+1/2} - u_{j-1/2} \right)
$$

with linear interpolation, which as you pointed out would give a second order accurate central difference.

Could I also use?

$$
u_x(x_j) = \frac{1}{h_{+}}\left( u_{j+1} - u_{j} \right)
$$

In my comment below, this is what I was getting at. How do define the $u_x(x_j)$ for the second equation, what are the pros. and cons. of using a central or upwinding scheme for this term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Second equation**
>
> However, how should the second equation be written, can I do the
>   following?
>
> $$ \int_{\Omega}w_t~dx = \int_{\Omega}\mathcal{F}~dx + \int_{\Omega}g(x,u,w)~dx \\ \tilde{w}_t =
>  \frac{1}{h_j}\mathcal{F}_jh_j + \tilde{g}(x_j,u_j,w_j) $$
>
> Moreover, if we assume that the flux in the $j$-th cell is constant
>   across the cell then the  integral becomes,
>
> $$ \int_{\Omega}\mathcal{F}~dx = \mathcal{F}_jh_j $$

This is also true if the flux is *linear* in the cell, not just constant.

> **Q1.** Is this correct?

Yes.

> However, $u_x$ is not known.
>
> **Q2.** Can I simply write $u_x$ using the values of concentration interpolated to the cell faces? For example,
>
> $$ u_x = \frac{1}{h_j}\left( u_{j+\frac{1}{2}} - u_{j-\frac{1}{2}} \right) $$

Yes, in finite difference/volume you generally have to compute the derivatives from the conserved variables. Note that to find the derivative $u_x$ at $j$ you can use a central difference (which may be unstable depending on the form of the diffusion and you might need to apply upwinding), which would be

$$ u_{x,j} = \frac{1}{2h} (u_{j+1} - u_{j-1}) + O(h^2)$$

assuming constant $h$ cell size. If you were using a linear interpolation to find $u_{j-1/2} = 1/2(u_{j-1}+u_{j})$ you can see that the above expression for central differencing using $j+1$ and $j-1$ is exactly the same as your $ u_x = \frac{1}{h_j}\left( u_{j+\frac{1}{2}} - u_{j-\frac{1}{2}} \right) $

Comment: Thank you! The diffusion component to the flux is $du_x$ where $d>0$ so is it correct that upwinding can be introduced by choosing, $$du_x = \frac{d}{h}(u_{j+1} - u_{j})$$ (assuming constant step size)? The advantages of upwind would be that is prevents oscillation when $u_x$ is very large (sharp gradients). What would be the other benefits and how do I know which scheme (central or upwind) is more stable?

Comment: Not quite. You don't upwind the diffusive operator, but rather the advective one. Physically you can understand this as diffusion happening in all directions (elliptical) and advection having a direction (hyperbolic) - you can't smell things downwind from you. You'll find this exact question in any intro CFD text - look for von Neumann stability analysis. And first look at strictly the advection equation and be able to solve that before adding diffusion.

Character-limited answer: Central is more accurate (2nd order), but unstable. Simple upwinding is stable, but only first order accurate.

Comment: You picked up all the important points in less that 500  characters, impressive! What I was asking (it's slightly unclear) is how to define the flux term $F_j$. I have made an update which hopefully clarifies what I mean.

Comment: There's a few methods, but one of the huge achievements in cfd history is this http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUSCL_scheme follow that scheme exactly for determining face fluxes and you'll be good to go.

Comment: The MUSCL seems to be a good solution, in that quantities will all remain positive in the equation (I need the solution to remain positive for a physical valid simulation). However, I would first like to implement the simplest approach. Am I correct in saying that if I use an **upwind** discretisation for $u_x$ (see the updated above), then this second equation will remain positive? A central discretisation would cause oscillations.

Comment: Yup that will work.